# Elegant way of harnessing facebook ads data without api

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-ads-api

I was helping one of my relatives with a Facebook campaign for their store.The campaign was a success as we gathered about more than 1000  new likes and a lot of queries.They were happy but I really wanted to do some more with that data like tag those people who liked if their setting allowed or send a message on messenger for arrival of new items.In short keep a track of the all that was happening.The idea is to harness the data so that maximum can be achieved next time on similar campaigns.

I wanted a something simple so that the guys at the store can do it themselves without any fiddling with api.After some trial and error i came up with this js code which can be pasted into console after opening the window which appears when you click link just on the side of like button.

```
 /*a script to get all the people who liked the page
     after a facebook campaign. A successful capmpaign will get 1000's of 
     likes so it will be impossible to load all the names in one go.Also the 
     list loads progressively with each scroll. So 
     the code introduces a last element in the json which you have to put in 
     place of "i" in the given code when you press see more button in 
     subsequent runs.On my fairly powerful laptop and decent internet I was 
     not able to get more than 350 persons without a good lag.

     The value of i is calculated by trial and error as the data attributes ` 
     before that holds something else(not required) and not the names.I hope 
     it will be more or less similar in all of them.
     This code is to be pasted in the console once the window with all the 
     likes is opened.*/


    var arrayName = document.querySelectorAll('[data-gt]');
    var PersonObject={};
    try {
    for(var i = 55;i<=arrayName.length;i++ ){
        var element=arrayName[i];
        console.log(element);
        var name=element.innerHTML;
        // console.log(i)
        PersonObject[("name"+i)]=name;
        // console.log(PersonObject)
        }
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log("error occured at"+i)
}
    finally{
       PersonObject["lastElement"]=i;
       var NamesJson = JSON.stringify(PersonObject)
       console.log(NamesJson)
}
```

I tried to write the gist of code in comments.

Now my real question,this all seems so hacky and patched stuff but not elegant. Isn't there a way for business owners to actually harness this data in more systematic way without the need for any api's  or any programming knowledge?

Comment: You should really double-check the terms & conditions, I think … just because someone liked your page, even if it was due to an ad they clicked, does not automatically mean that you also have the right to personally contact them now.

Comment: Will do that and get back to you.However,isnt it really troubling that you spend money on ads but can't convert them into leads.Defies the basic logic of advertisement.However,i was in no way going to randomly contact them but appropriately filter them and see actually who would be a prospective customer by obviously looking at their profiles.FYI,looking to target new home owners or someone into renovation.So, I do have an a idea of a age group and location because they roughly translate into economic capacity here in Kathmandu,Nepal.

Comment: I will be very glad if you could guide me about the possibility of the action I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: There's a type of ads specifically for [lead generation](https://www.facebook.com/business/a/lead-ads), and for those you get the user's contact info via an API or downloaded spreadsheet (and there's a t&cs that covers your use of that data) - check that option out instead of trying to scrape data from Facebook's website - as far as I'm aware there's no cost premium for that type of ad versus any other with the same targeting and performance

Comment: Thanks.Didnt know ,something like that existed.